# Clip analysis in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, clip

I have one shapefile that covers an entire city. I also have a list of 100 shapefiles which are buffers in different places in the city. Now I want to clip for each buffer from that city using ArcMap and python. I tried using arcpy in python but the code is not working.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "U:\Park and Residential Area\Test\SBA park_res_buffer_5\SBA.gdb"
infeature= "U:\Park and Residential Area\Test\park_res_merge.shp"
clipfeatture = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "polygon")
for i in clipfeatture:
    outclipfeatture = arcpy.Clip_analysis(infeature,i)
    outclipfeatture.save("U:\Park and Residential Area\Test\SBA park_res_buffer_5/"*i)
```

This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#10>", line 3, in <module> outclipfeatture.save("U:\Park and Residential Area\Test\SBA park_res_buffer_5/"*i)
AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: What are the results of your current code? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: This is the error i get:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 3, in <module>
    outclipfeatture.save("U:\Park and Residential Area\Test\SBA park_res_buffer_5/"*i)
AttributeError: 'Result' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: You may want to try using the raw string form for the URLs. Example: 
r"U:\Park and Residential Area\Test\SBA park_res_buffer_5\SBA.gdb" in order to avoid having to escape the back slashes.  Also did you mean to use a + instead of a * in the last expression?

Answer (score 6):

[`arcpy.Clip_analysis()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) has 3 required parameters: `in_features`, `clip_features`, and `out_feature_class`. You're only supplying the first two. Additionally, there is no `save` method for the [`Result` object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm), as your error message indicates.

Instead, you should set `outclipfeatture = r"U:\path\to\output.shp"` (which will need to be unique for each clip feature) and then call `arcpy.Clip_analysis(infeature, i, outclipfeatture)`. This will create the output shapefile and save the result to it.

---

One other note: your current paths will not be interpreted correctly. You either need to convert them to raw strings by placing an `r` in front of the string as in my example, change your backslashes (\) to forward slashes (/), or double them up (\\) so they are properly escaped.